# If p is prime and p|$a^n$ prove that $p^n|a^n$

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

If p is prime and p|$a^n$ prove that $p^n|a^n$.

I understand the idea but am having some trouble writing the formal proof.

Is this correct?

Suppose $p$ is prime and $p$|$a^n$. Then $p|a$ $\implies $$a=pk$ , $k$ $\in \mathbb{Z}.$
But then $a^n $= $(pk)^n$=$p^nk^n$ and so $p^n$|$p^nk^n$. Hence $p^n$|$a^n$

Comment: From the first division, can you conclude $p\mid a$?

Comment: I can conclude that but i am not exactly sure how to connect it to the 2nd part

Answer (score 13):

Hint: If $p$ is prime and $p|ab$ then $p|a$ or $p|b$.

Answer (score 1):

From $p \ | \ a^n$ we get that $p$ is a prime factor of $a^n$.  Now assume $p \nmid a$, then since $p \ | \ a^n$ this implies that two factors of $a$ (possibly the same and both greater than 1) call them $k, m$ exist such that  $p=km$ which is absurd since, again, $p$ is prime.  These factors would be coming from different terms in the $a^n$ expansion.

Comment: I find this argument very unconvincing.

Comment: Yeah, I dunno. This always made sense to me without a formal proof. I edited it a bit but really azarel nailed it.